# Import Serialized Data to Laravel 8 giving PHP_Incomplete_Class error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, deserialization

I'm attempting to import data from an existing database into a new Laravel 8 app.
All was going well until I ran into some serialized data in one field.

Example serialized data coming from the old database:

```
a:1:{i:0;O:11:"pubBranches":5:{s:2:"id";i:0;s:4:"name";s:17:"Publication Title";s:4:"file";s:22:"M:\PathToFile\file.pdf";s:7:"comment";s:0:"";s:9:"printinfo";s:0:"";}}
```

Here's my seeder file:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Publication;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class pubBranches
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $file;
    public $comment;
    public $printinfo;
    public $status;
}

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $publications = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('publications')->select('*')->get();
        $this->command->info('Importing publications');
        foreach ($publications as $pub) {
            $publication = Publication::create([
                'id' => $pub->id,
                'parent' => $pub->parent,
                'title' => $pub->title,
                'subtitle' => $pub->subtitle,
                'author' => $pub->author,
            ]);
            $pubmeta = unserialize($pub->files);
            if ($pubmeta != "") {
                dd($pubmeta);
                foreach ($pubmeta as $key => $meta) {
                    $publication->setMeta('id', $pubmeta->id);
                }
            }
            $publication->save();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get at the dd: `0 => __PHP_Incomplete_Class(pubBranches) {#1801`

There's probably something simple, but I've been beating my head for a long time now.

Comment: You may have serialised the class before adding a namespace to the file it's declared in because it's been serialised as `pubBranches` instead of `Database\Seeders\pubBranches`. It may work you you add a [`class_alias`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) to it but in general I would not recommend having multiple classes in a single file because it gives you

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos Now I understand how namespaces work, and I go the data accessible!